# Android percent field field fill too much

Tags: android

In my android app i am finding the percent of 2 other counters
with this code

```
double total1 =  counter + counter1;
double totaal2 = counter / total1 * 100.0;
            percentfield.setText("" + total2);
```

My codes work great when the percent field is showing 50%, 25% etc.
But its showing 33.33333333333%
Is there a way, to short down my percent field too only showing 33.3

**Edit**
I have short it down with this code under layout.xml

```
android:maxLength="3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    totaal2  = totaal2  * 10;
    totaal2  = Math.round(totaal2 );
    totaal2  = totaal2  / 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using many ways. Better use this approach, I found this a long back and it worked for me:

```
public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
{
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
return rounded.doubleValue();
}
```

e.g.,  round(yourNumber, 3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat to format your doubles to a string.

e.g.

```
double total1 =  counter + counter1;
double totaal2 = counter / total1 * 100.0;

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
percentfield.setText(formatter.format(total2));
```

See the documentation on DecimalFormat: 
[Decimal Format JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)